# Writing a Python module to import other modules

Tags: python, import, module

I want to write a Python module that automatically imports all the good stuff for me (about 50 other modules) so I don't have to copy and past them every time I start a new script. I attempted this by defining the following method in my module, soon to realize when I import my module and call this method, the imports take place locally.

```
def auto_import():
    import os
    import sys
    # plus 50 other modules...
```

How can I accomplish this automation using modular programming? (I am using Python 3.6. on Ubuntu.)

Comment: If every script you write *needs* to import 50 other modules, you have a problem.

Comment: Don't put the imports in the function

Comment: It's hypothetical @user2357112, but in data science, one needs to import numpy, scipy, pytorch and 5 other modules it comes with pytorch, sys, os, matplotlib, and ................................. 40 others, plus my personal modules and so on. I am not developing a software, I use these for one-time data analysis.

Comment: @ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000, I am open to suggestions. What do you recomend instead?

Comment: Exactly what is below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a function to do that, you can simply make a file like `commonimports.py` which looks like this:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import sys
#and so on...
```

And add this `import` statement in other files

```
from commonimports import *
```

And you'll have all the modules ready to use within that namespace

Comment: Wonderful, I just successfully tested it and my code loos so much cleaner. Thank you Ofer for getting back to me so quickly :)

Comment: Glad to be able to help you

Answer (score -1):

Just make the name of your imported modules global:

```
def auto_import():
    import os
    import sys    
    global os, sys
```

Answer (score -2):

This is not necessary to use this method if you def auto_import() then every time you have to use a  autoimport function whenever you want to use those module.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am not sure what you mean. Your explanation is not clear.

Comment: What he meant was, when you define it in a function, you have to use the relevant imports inside the same function. when the code goes out of the scope of the function, all imports that you have done inside the function gets deleted

Comment: This makes no sense. It kind of sounds like you mixed up functions and classes, but either way, it doesn't make sense.